# Hide/unhide sheet with specific name using VB

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write function, that will hide all sheets in my workbook where sheet name begin with specific characters (sheet name will begin with characters: *frm* -> *frm*List, *frm*Check, *frm*Load, ...).
Then I would like to show/unhide specific sheet when I will call them. Let say that I am in Sheet1 and I would like to show (open) frmList (when go back to Sheet1, frmList should became invisible again).
Thanks.

What I do was to put code (for hidining)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
Me.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End Sub
```

in every sheet I would like to hide. Is there any option to use for all shets where name begin with specific characters (*frm*)?

For unhiding sheets I use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim shtName As String
    'shtName = Target.Name

    shtName = Left(Target.SubAddress, InStr(1, Target.SubAddress, "!") - 1)
    Sheets(shtName).Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets(shtName).Select
End Sub
```

**EDIT** with loop

Ok, I loop for sheet name and hide them.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

If ws.name Like "obr" & "*" Then
    '''ws.Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
     '  ws.Me.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
     ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
End If
Next ws
```

If I use as `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` I can not update my forms, because every time I change something inn those sheet it hide it(when press enter/return). How can I set, that if sheet is active, will not hide after pressing enter. It should hide only when go back to other sheet via hyperlink (click on text with hyperlink to "main" sheet) or just click on other sheet name.

Comment: How will you call the sheets?

Comment: Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question. • [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: You would need to loop through all sheets and check if their name begins with `frm` if so hide it, if not don't.